# Wordpress Editar Upload de Mídia

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, woocommerce

Não estou conseguindo identificar no Wordpress onde está o arquivo para editar a parte que seleciona arquivos para o upload (escolher a imagem), conforme a foto abaixo:

[image: Selecionar arquivos][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZNjb.png)

Alguém sabe como editar essa parte para eu poder centralizar os botões e os textos?

Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Essa tela não é exatamente editável, já que ela fazer parte do core do WordPress. Mas você consegue personalizar algumas coisas adicionando um css seu no admin.

Por exemplo, consegui centralizar o botão primeiro ao adicionar um css com esta linha no functions.php do meu tema:

```
$my_theme_versao = '1.0.0.0';
function my_theme_admin_enqueue($hook) {
    global $my_theme_versao;
    wp_enqueue_style('my_theme-admin-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin.css', array(), $my_theme_versao);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_admin_enqueue');
```

E no css, com as regras sendo mais específicas que o css original do WordPress, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
body .media-toolbar-primary.search-form {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
body .media-modal-content .media-toolbar-primary .media-button{
    float: none;
}
```